# Editing a row or setting state from inside the selection component

Tags: reactjs, devexpress

I have a DevExpress `Grid` with an `EditingState` and a `SelectionState`. The general idea is that I want to add rows that have been either edited or selected (via the checkboxes) to a `React.useState()` variable, because I am going to pass that list of rows to a webservice "Save" function.

I made an MVCE by combining the following two demos: [Editing](https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/grid/docs/guides/editing/) and [Selection](https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/grid/docs/guides/selection/), which you can find here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-bhabha-p05lm?file=/demo.js

The key piece is here:

```
const [updateArray, setUpdateArray] = React.useState([]);

...

function onSelectionChange(selectedRows) {
    const data = Object.assign([], rows);
    // selection is the array of previously selected rows, selectedRows are the ones now selected
    const rowsChecked = selectedRows.filter(x => !selection.includes(x));
    const rowsUnchecked = selection.filter(x => !selectedRows.includes(x));
    setSelection(selectedRows);
    rowsChecked.forEach(item => {
      const rowIndex = data.findIndex(obj => obj.id === item);
      data[rowIndex].car = "NEW CAR";
      setUpdate(true, data[rowIndex]);
    });
    rowsUnchecked.forEach(item => {
      const rowIndex = data.findIndex(obj => obj.id === item);
      data[rowIndex].car = "OLD CAR";
      if (data[rowIndex].city === "New York") {
        setUpdate(true, data[rowIndex]);
      } else {
        setUpdate(false, data[rowIndex]);
      }
    });
}
```

Because this `setUpdate` function is inside the Selection component, which is inside the grid, I get the error (technically warning, but the call to setUpdate fails) that

> index.js:1 Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component. in SelectionStateBase (at selection.js:24)*.

If I edit a row or select an individual row, it seems to work, but I am unable to use the "select all" feature to add all of the selected items to the `updateArray`.

I read that you are not supposed to synchronously call `setState` inside other functional components and to defer the call to `useEffect`, but I have tried all sorts of combinations of `React.useEffect()` and `React.useCallback()` and have had no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue :** **[DO READ](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value)**

```
function setUpdate(isAdd, row) {

    // `updateArray` will be pointing to the old array
    const rows = Object.assign([], updateArray);
    const copy = rows.filter(i => i.name !== row.name || i.city !== row.city);
    if (isAdd) {
      copy.push(row);
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(copy));

    // 1. this will update updateArray asynchronously , so you wont get updated `updateArray`
    // on first line of function when its called second,third,forth ... quickly
    // which happens when you select all, it will still point to the old `updateArray`
    setUpdateArray(copy);
  }
```

**Solution :**

```
  function setUpdate(isAdd, row) {

    setUpdateArray((updateArray) => { // this will provide latest copy of state

      // so here you will always get updated `updateArray`
      const rows = Object.assign([], updateArray);
      const copy = rows.filter(i => i.name !== row.name || i.city !== row.city);
      if (isAdd) {
        copy.push(row);
      }
      console.log(JSON.stringify(copy));
      return copy;
    });

  }
```

**Hope this will help you to get understanding of issue and how to solve it.**

**WORKING DEMO :**

[image: Edit so-state-update-issue]